# Create a global grid in kilometer in Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude

What is the best way to create a regular squared global grid in kilometer ? Creating it in degrees is easy but i would like to specifiy the input mesh size in kilometers ?

I was thinking using

- Latitude: 1 deg = 110.574 km
- Longitude: 1 deg = 111.320 * cos(latitude) km

as reported in :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253499/simple-calculations-for-working-with-lat-lon-and-km-distance

It would be something like this :

```
import numpy as np
import shapely

latmin = -90
latmax = 90
lonmin = -180
lonmax= 180
stepsize = 10

range_latitude = np.arange(latmin, latmax+stepsize, stepsize)
range_longitude = np.arange(lonmin, lonmax+stepsize, stepsize)
liste_point = []
for lat in range_latitude:
    for lon in range_longitude:
        p = shapely.geometry.Point([lon*111.320*np.cos(np.radians(lat)), lat*110.574])
        liste_point.append(p)
```

Does it make sense ? In that case, if i want to stack my list of point in a geodataframe, what kind of projection it is related to ?

Comment: There are other trials about covering the globe with grids. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_global_grid and https://docs.ogc.org/per/20-039r2.html.

Comment: No, you can't create a regular grid across the globe, for the same reason you can't wrap a baseball in graph paper and keep the lines orthogonal. You can, as I have, generate a grid of *equal-area* "rectangles" (actually spheroidal trapezoids), by choosing an an arbitrary fixed width (in degrees longitude), and scaling the height of each rectangle so that it has the same area (using a trapezoid equation, iterating to fudge to tolerance) -- cells near the Equator will be squat while polar cells will be tall.

Comment: I understand you followed something like this method : https://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/pers/2005journal/may/2005_may_623-627.pdf
Have you implemented it in python ?